# How to start a service as Protected Process Light (PPL)?

Tags: windows, process, protected-mode

I'm making a service. I use .NET Framework. 
I want to start the service as a protected process light. I want to make it so unprotected processes can't inject DLLs, terminate, suspend, resume, or any kind of control to my process. I created a DWORD in the service's key called LaunchProtected and set its value to 3. And then I restarted my machine. The service can't start, when I tried to start it, it shown:

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 577:
Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.
```

I can't delete or modify the service's configuration, and I can't do anything with it. When I try to do a thing with it on admin CMD, it shown:

```
[SC] OpenService FAILED 5:
Access is denied.
```

Some service also have the LaunchProtected key with value 3, 2 or 1, when I tried to start them, they can start normally. Like the WinDefend service.

Comment: just a guess, but your service probably isn't signed by a trusted code signing key. I'm guessing that starting a process with a high integrity level will require that that software be signed by a MS recognized key.

Comment: this may help: http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=146